# python interpreter throwing a type error where there is none

Tags: python, class, pygame, typeerror

i am trying to create a drop down like feature in pygame. The program consists of the "Drop" class which has texts on it and describes the general purpose of the drop down menu. Then there is the wrapper class which contains all the different labels on the drop down menu. The Child class is the label and can be added on to the wrapper class via the "add_child" function which is where the error is occurring.

```
import pygame as pg


doc = "c:/users/user/documents/code/py/pg/project/"
vec = pg.math.Vector2


class Drop(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        self.parent = parent

        default = {
            "size":[100, 25],
            "pos":vec(0, 0),
            "bg":pg.Color("#ff0000"),
        }

        for key, value in default.items():
            if key not in kwargs:
                kwargs[key] = value

        self.size = kwargs["size"]
        self.pos = vec(kwargs["pos"])
        self.bg = kwargs["bg"]

        super().__init__()

        class Child(Sprite):
            def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
                self.parent = parent

                default = {
                    "size":[100, 25],
                    "pos":vec(0, 0),
                    "bg":pg.Color("#00ff00")
                }

                for key, value in default.items():
                    if key not in kwargs and key != "name":
                        kwargs[key] = value

                self.size = kwargs["size"]
                self.pos = vec(kwargs["pos"])
                self.bg = kwargs["bg"]
                self.name = kwargs["name"]

                super().__init__()

            def render(self):
                self.parent.image.blit(self.image, self.rect)


        class Wraper(Sprite):
            def __init__(self, parent, index=1):

                self.index = index
                self.children = [] # childs which are labels with texts on it

                self.parent = {
                    "0":parent.parent,
                    "1":parent.parent.parent
                }[str(self.index)]

                self.y = {
                    "0":parent.pos.y + parent.size[1],
                    "1":parent.parent.pos.y + parent.parent.size[1]
                }[str(self.index)]


                self.size = [100, 100]
                self.bg = pg.Color("#000000")

                self.x = self.parent.pos.x
                self.pos = vec(self.x, self.y)

                super().__init__()
                # this is a custom sprite initialization class i'ts not the problem


            def add_child(self, **kwargs):
                self.children.append(Child(self, kwargs))

                # this is where the interpreter throws the error
                # aperantly the child class takes 2 positional arguments
                # but i gave 3. but as you can see there are clearly only
                # two arguments given, the parent parameter and kwargs

            def render(self):
                if self.children:
                    for child in self.children:
                        child.render()


                if hasattr(self.parent, "image"):
                    self.parent.image.blit(self.image, self.rect)
                else:
                    self.parent.blit(self.image, self.rect)

        self.wraper = Wraper(self, 1)


    def render(self):
        self.wraper.render()
        self.parent.image.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

the error:

152, in add_child
    self.children.append(Child(self, kwargs))
TypeError: **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `Child(self, **kwargs)`, not just `Child(self, kwargs)`. It is trying to send it as an argument, when you want a keyword.